# Python importing from MS Access: "Invalid connection string attribute"

Tags: python, ms-access, python-3.3

I am trying to import data from a MS Access database

```
import pyodbc

connStr = """

import pypyodbc
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}
DBQ = C:\\Users\\haesh\\Desktop\\Comp Sci CC\\Database1.accdb;

"""
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
```

However I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\haesh\Desktop\Comp Sci CC\qwerty.py", line 10, in <module>
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
pyodbc.Error: ('01S00', '[01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import pypyodbc` does not belong in the ODBC connection string. Also, connection strings can be confused by line breaks and white space. You should have better luck with this:

```python
connStr = (
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"DBQ=C:\Users\haesh\Desktop\Comp Sci CC\Database1.accdb;"
    )
```